# pytest missing logging output of subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pytest

When writing tests for parts of a program that uses multiprocessing, pytest seems to be unable to access the logs of the subprocess.

Minimal example:

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def _foo():
    logging.error("foo")


def test_foo(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.WARNING):
        _foo()
        assert "foo" in caplog.messages


def _bar():
    logging.error("bar")


def test_bar(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.WARNING):
        p = Process(target=_bar)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        assert "bar" in caplog.messages
```

The log output from subprocesses in the terminal for failed tests is also missing. At least the option `--log-cli-level=DEBUG` seems to work in this case.

Is there an way to get the complete logs with caplog or show the missing logs for failed tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module has a limitation that you may have run into and that can cause problem because the `logging` module in the new process is completely separate from the one in the parent process.

Lets try to redirect its standard output and standard error to a file or a pipe and then read from that file or pipe in the main process.

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import io
import os

def _bar():
    logging.error("bar")

def test_bar(caplog):
    read_end, write_end = os.pipe()

    with caplog.at_level(logging.WARNING):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=_bar, kwargs={'stdout': write_end, 'stderr': write_end})
        p.start()
        os.close(write_end)
        output = io.open(read_end).read()
        p.join()

    assert "bar" in output
```

Comment: So I though about it wrongly: it is not a limitation of pytest but a limitation of logging in a multiprocessing context in general. Thank you for the clarification. I wonder if there is an elegant way of feeding the log messages of perpetually passing the log output of child processes to the parent process that initializes the logger?

Comment: You could look into multiprocessing.Queue, the child processes put their log records into the queue, and the parent process has a log handler which reads from the queue and handles the log records